# Visual Studio 2020 Hot Reload isn't working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, hot-reload

I am using Visual Studio 2022 v 17.2.1 to create an ASP.NET Core/6 app.

When I make `HTML` only changes to my Razor Views, and I try to hot reload the page, I get the following

[image]

Here are my Hot-Reload settings

[image]

How can I get the Hot-Reload function working so I don't have to restart my app every time I want to see the change in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are using Response Compression Middleware (`UseResponseCompression()`) in the `Program.cs` file.

It seems that this middleware [is no longer needed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/blazor-webassembly-3-2-0-preview-2-release-now-available/comment-page-3/#:%7E:text=app.UseResponseCompression()) for Blazor Webassembly, and that for some people [removing the installation of the middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41732#:%7E:text=Hot%20reload%20works%20when%20I%20remove) `UseResponseCompression()` fixes the problem of getting an error when attempting to hot reload. Some Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server#:%7E:text=Add-,Response%20Compression%20Middleware,-services%20to%20Program) says to use the compression middleware, but this breaks the hot reload functionality, in my exprience. Once this call is removed, hot reload works for running with the Debugger attached and not attached.